# How to animate each element's jquery function before moving to the next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone give me some reference or code for how to animate each element's jquery function before moving to the next link/page?

For example: I am planning to create a small HTML page with few elements like logo, one pic and one introduction paragraph. All these three elements animate and appear when the page loads and after this, when user click the next page I would like to have an effect like all these three elements animates (reverse animation) and then moves to the next page.

I have created a demo below:

https://jsfiddle.net/k1yt78fh/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".logo").animate({left: '5%'}, "slow");
 $(".nav").delay(800).animate({right: '5%'}, "slow");
 $(".intro").delay(1600).animate({left: '5%'}, "slow");
 $(".pic").delay(2400).animate({right: '3%'}, "slow");
});
```

```css
body {
   background: #000;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  .container {
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0 auto !important;
   position: relative;
  }
  
  .logo {
   width: 200px;
   height: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left:-100%;
   top: 0px;
   color: #FFF000;
   font-weight: bolder;
   margin-top: 20px;
   font-size: 20px;
  }
  .nav {
   width: auto;
   position: absolute;
   right:-100%;
   top: 0px;
   
   margin-bottom: 20px
  }
  .nav a {
   color: #FFF;
   
   }
  
  .intro {
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   left:-100%;
   top: 18%;
   color: #FFF;
   margin-top: 20%;
   
  }
  .intro strong {
   color: #FF0000;
  }
  
  .pic { 
   width: 40%;
   position: absolute;
   right:-100%;
   top: 15%;
   margin-top: 8%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
 
 
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="logo">
   Logo Name
  </div>
  
  <div class="nav">
   <a href="animateout.html">Page 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="animateout2.html">Page 2</a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="intro">
    <strong>Page 1</strong> <br>

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
  </div>
  
  <div class="pic">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?random" />
  </div>
  
  
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add the same jquery function to the links and reverse the direction.

Comment: Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @wazz, for your time and really appreciated. You can see in above jsfiddle link what i have done so far. I actually don't know how to do this task. all those three elements animations reverse (animate out from the page) should happen then go to the next link or page when user click on the nav link. This is what am looking for.

Comment: @bootstrap use negative values to remove them from the page. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are trying to make the animation occur one after the other by using the `delay()` method. You can remove that and simply call each *next* animation in a callback to the animate method.

To reverse your animation when the user wishes to navigate to the next page simply call your `animation()` methods in reverse order and prevent the default click action when the link to the next page is clicked. Also, provide `-100%` value to all dimensions, so that they animate out of the page.

Finally, you redirect to next page after the *reverse* animation is complete.

Here is the modified code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".logo").animate({left: '5%'}, "slow", function() { 
        $(".nav").animate({right: '5%'}, "slow", function() {
            $(".intro").animate({left: '5%'}, "slow", function() {
                $(".pic").animate({right: '3%'}, "slow");
            });
        });
    });

    $("a[href='animateout2.html']").on('click', function(e) {
        $(".pic").animate({right: '-100%'}, "slow", function() { 
            $(".intro").animate({left: '-100%'}, "slow", function() {
                $(".nav").animate({right: '-100%'}, "slow", function() {
                    $(".logo").animate({left: '-100%'}, "slow", function() {
                        window.location.href = $(e.target).prop('href');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
```

```css
body {
   background: #000;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  .container {
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0 auto !important;
   position: relative;
  }
  
  .logo {
   width: 200px;
   height: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left:-100%;
   top: 0px;
   color: #FFF000;
   font-weight: bolder;
   margin-top: 20px;
   font-size: 20px;
  }
  .nav {
   width: auto;
   position: absolute;
   right:-100%;
   top: 0px;
   
   margin-bottom: 20px
  }
  .nav a {
   color: #FFF;
   
   }
  
  .intro {
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   left:-100%;
   top: 18%;
   color: #FFF;
   margin-top: 20%;
   
  }
  .intro strong {
   color: #FF0000;
  }
  
  .pic { 
   width: 40%;
   position: absolute;
   right:-100%;
   top: 15%;
   margin-top: 8%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
 
 
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="logo">
   Logo Name
  </div>
  
  <div class="nav">
   <a href="animateout.html">Page 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="animateout2.html">Page 2</a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="intro">
    <strong>Page 1</strong> <br>

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
  </div>
  
  <div class="pic">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?random" />
  </div>
  
  
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

If you include class names in all your links like this:

```
<a class='page1' href="animateout.html">Page 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class='page2' href="animateout2.html">Page 2</a>
<a class='page3' href="animateout3.html">Page 3</a>
```

then replace

```
$("a[href='animateout2.html']").on('click'...
```

with

```
$('.page2').on('click'...
```

in the jquery script.

You may also wish to Target every other link apart from the first one by using

```
$('.page2, .page3').on('click'...
```

Comment: Thanks @Udo E. Is there a way to remove the link location from the javascript ($("a[href='animateout2.html']"))? Secondly, Do we have a reverse function in jquery that will be just one line code instead of writing all the elements in reverse order? Thanks for your time & Really appreciated.

Comment: Also, what if there is one more link as "page 3" so how can i modify the javascript ( $("a[href='animateout2.html']").on('click', function(e)  ) ?

Comment: E, Thanks you so much! This is exactly what i am looking for. Just a last question. Also, only jQuery's slideUp() and slideDown() method will meet your specification of "one line code". --- How's this is possible in a single line?

Comment: @bootstrap, Sorry, only `slideToggle()` will truly achieve this. In your case you are performing the animation one element at a time. So the "one line code" may not apply. If you are animating all elements at the same time you could use `$('.element1, .element2, ...').slideToggle('slow', function () {})`.  In the case of `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` the only advantage you have is that you do not supply any css property modification parameters.

Comment: @bootstrap, I correct my earlier comments. `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` won't meet the "one line code" specification. It's `slideToggle()` that would as in my previous comment.